# How to correctly connect my php (symfony) container with mysql container?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, doctrine, database-connection

I was trying to connect php container with symfony 4 with mysql container and I got this error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Unknown host.
```

I can connect with mysql through phpmyadmin.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        command:
            - "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"
        container_name: sf4_mysql
        volumes:
            - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: sf4
            MYSQL_USER: sf4
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: sf4

    php:
        build: .docker/php
        container_name: sf4_php
        volumes:
          - .:/home/wwwroot/sf4
        environment:
          - maildev_host=sf4_maildev
        depends_on:
          - maildev
          - mysql

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: sf4_phpmyadmin
        environment: 
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            PMA_PORT: 3306
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        links:
            - mysql
```

and .env file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://sf4:sf4@mysql/sf4
```

This is my doctrine.yaml file. I have removed unnecessary comments.

```
parameters:
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '8.0'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

This is my current [repository](https://github.com/Raloriz/first-docker)
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port is missing.

Try

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://sf4:sf4@mysql:3306/sf4
```

Reminder :

Make sure to execute symfony commands from inside the container after logging in with the command :

```
docker-compose exec php bash
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191471/discussion-on-answer-by-abdelkarim-el-amel-how-to-correctly-connect-my-php-symf).